# Can't create /etc/passwd.xxx file but can create /etc/test file in centos

Tags: centos, permissions, write

I'm using an AWS image that for some reason is configured such that I can't seem to create any file named /etc/passwd.xxx  (insert anything for the x).  I can create files named test, test.xxx etc, it seems to only forbid creating the file if it starts with passwd.

This is a problem because the groupmod command tries to create a passwd.xxxxx, where the x are random numbers, file whenever it is run.  Presumably after creating the file it would switch the passwd with passwd.xxxxx file, but it doesn't get that far because it fails to create the passwd.xxxxx file.  This in turn causes my ansible scripts to fail if a group I'm creating already exists with a different GID.

So the question is why would only files with a specific structure be refused to be created while all other files can be created.

Strace gives the, less then useful error

```
open("/etc/passwd.23491" O_WRONGLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC 0600) = -1 EACCESS (Permission denied)
```

I'm using sudo for everything.

/etc has 755 permissions and lsattr for /etc is

```
---------I--e-- /etc
```

I already checked and capital I is not the same as lower case i.  cap I means it's indexed using hashed trees

I've tried setting selinux into permissive mode and the issue still occures.  Looking at the selinux logs the only avc denied error is for a comm of sshd and name of eic_run_authorized_keys, which I doubt is related to passwd file creation.  I can see syscalls for groupmod, but no obvious error associated with them.

Why can't I create passwd.xxxx files and how do I fix it to allow that?

Comment: Probably a security framework. I think SELinux can't distinguish between file names when creating files, but AppArmor can, so check `/etc/apparmor*`. There's probably a log file tracking denied attempts: check `find /var/log -mmin -5` after a failed attempt.

Comment: The question is tagged CentOS, so SELinux is the most likely security framework. Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for messages with `avc: denied` in them.

Comment: @telcoM a good idea, but the only avc: denied I see seem to be for sshd and besides I tried switching selinux to permissive and the issue still occurs.  I'll update my question.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' there is no /etc/app* files, don't think apparmor is installed.  I already looked through all the recently changed files in logs and didn't see any obviously relevant error messages